# Change the URL in chrome after the page has loaded

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've written the following script to change the URL of a tab in Chrome, but can't figure out how to get it to automatically run on every page.

```
  var nytimes = /.*nytimes\.com.*/;
  var patt = /(&gwh=).*$/;

  function updateUrl(tab){
   if(tab.url.match(nytimes))
   {
    var newUrl = tab.url.replace(patt,"");
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: newurl});
   }
  }
 chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tab) {updateUrl(tab);});
```

I put that into my background page, but it isn't working. Do I need to put the code somewhere else to get it to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suggest you read about [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html). They are exactly what you're looking for but you need to understand that they have limited access to the Chrome.* API, so you'll have to use [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) in order to use your current functionality. However, by using content scripts you can probably make this simpler using one of my proposed solutions.

### Solution 1

Assuming you want to send the redirect to the same URL every time, you can easily configure your extension to only run your content script on the NY Times site. For example;

#### Content Script: `content.js`

```js
location = 'http://example.com';
```

### Solution 2

However, if the redirect URL can vary you many want to abstract that logic in to your [background page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html). For example;

#### Content Script: `content.js`

```js
// Or you can pass a more specific section of the URL (e.g. `location.pathname`)
chrome.extension.sendRequest({href: location.href}, function(data) {
  location = data.url;
});
```

#### Background Page: `background.js`

```js
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  sendResponse({
    url: getUrl(request.href) // TODO: `getUrl` method containing your logic...
  });
});
```

### Important!

Regardless of which approach you go for you will also need to request permission to run the content script on the target site in your [manifest file](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html).

#### Manifest: `manifest.json`

```js
{
  ...
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "matches": ["*://*.nytimes.com/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```